# unison: -force only on conflict

Tags: synchronization, unison

According to Unison Manual, using -force <*root*>:

> Including the preference -force root causes Unison to resolve all
>   differences (even non-conflicting changes) in favor of root.

However, I want to force it **only in conflicting changes**, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer just after posting, but I would like to keep it here for other people looking into the same problem:

In those cases, you should use "-prefer" instead of "-force" :

> Including the preference -prefer root causes Unison 
>   always to resolve conflicts in favor of root, 
>   rather than asking for guidance from the user. 
>   (The syntax of root is the same as for the root 
>   preference, plus the special values newer and older.)

That's all :)